# How to measure the state in superposition of two bits so that it collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I often hear that if we have state let say $|\psi\rangle$ in superposition of two bits,
$|\psi\rangle= |0\rangle+|1\rangle$. If we apply measurement for example $\sigma _z$ , it will collapse and we will get one bit. But When i apply $\sigma_z=|0\rangle\langle0|-|1\rangle\langle1|$ on $
|\psi\rangle$ , I get $|\psi\rangle= |0\rangle-|1\rangle$. How to get one bit after measurement?

Comment: How much do you know about quantum mechanics?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I took undergrad course of Quantum mechanics but this point always confused me.

Comment: You took an undergrad course on quantum mechanics and you don't know about projective measurements? What *do* you know about measurement (please add it to the question)?

Comment: I knew about projective measurement but in book i was reading , it was written "when we apply $\sigma_z$ to state $\psi$ defined above , it collapses.I was not understanding how it is collapsing.@NorbertSchuch

Comment: It seems that you have a strange concept of "qubit" -- you talk about "two qubits", but you have *one* qubit in a superposition of *two* "classical" states.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch in my experience undergrad QM courses don't focus too much on measurements, beyond the Born rule. They are more focused on diagonalising hamiltonians and such. As a matter of fact, I don't think I really understood measurement until I took a quantum information course.

Comment: @user2723984 Which is ironic, given that quantum mechanics is a theory about measurements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer directly your question, without going further into the details of quantum measurement (there is more to it than the below): when you measure an observable, in your case $\sigma_z$, the possible measurement outcomes are the eigenvalues, in your case $\pm 1$ (note that you labelled the state associated with outcome $-1$ as $|0\rangle$). The state immediately after the measurement is the projection onto the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue you obtained in the measurement. So, if your apparatus says $1$, the state is now $\langle\psi|1\rangle |1\rangle = |1\rangle$, if it says $-1$, the state is now $\langle\psi|1\rangle |0\rangle = |0\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

Measuring some observable $A$ of a system in state $|\psi\rangle$ does *not* mean looking at $A|\psi\rangle$.

To determine probabilities of measurement outcomes, expand your state in the eigenbasis of the observable. You have already done this. So your $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ tells us there is a $1/2$ probability of measuring state $|0\rangle$ and $1/2$ probability of measuring state $|1\rangle$.

Note that there is *no way* to determine what the outcome of a measurement is. All you can determine are probabilities of each outcome, as described above. More explicitly, if $|a_n\rangle$ are the set of eigenstates of observable $A$, we can express $|\psi\rangle$ as $|\psi\rangle=\sum_nc_n|a_n\rangle$ (with the appropriate normalization). Then the probability of getting a result of $a_n$ when measuring $A$ is $|c_n|^2=|\langle a_n|\psi\rangle|^2$. Note we did not determine $A|\psi\rangle$ here.

Comment: A more succinct way to say the same thing would be that the measurement of a state $|{\psi}\rangle$ with an operator $\hat{A}$ does not result into $\hat{A}|{\psi}\rangle$ but rather it results into the density matrix $\rho=\sum_n|\langle\psi|a_n\rangle|^2|a_n\rangle\langle a_n|$.